# Trying to implement a particles.js in my react+vite portfolio website

Tags: reactjs, json, vite, particles.js

I have been trying to find out why is particle.js not working properly in my project. I have installed all the packages, and tried isolating just the background. Tried changed zIndex values and it has not worked.

I am only able to see the plain background color or the json config that I am trying to use, but the particles are missing and are no where to be seen.

Please help as I have looked for help on many places but nothing has helped.

This is my app.jsx code

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { About, Contact, Experience, Feedbacks, Hero, Navbar, Tech, Works, StarsCanvas} from './components';
import ParticlesBg from './components/ParticlesBg'
const App = () => {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div >
    <ParticlesBg />
     <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Hero />
     </div>
     <div className='bg-white'>
     <About />
     </div>
     <Experience />
     <Tech />
     <Works />
     <Feedbacks />
     <div className='relative z-0'>
      <Contact />
      <StarsCanvas />
     </div>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is my particles file:

```
import React from "react";
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";

function ParticlesBg () {
    async function loadParticles(main) {
        await loadFull(main)
    }
    return(
        <Particles
        id="tsparticles"
        init={loadParticles}
        options = {{
            autoPlay: true,
            background: {
              color: {
                value: "#17163e"
              },
              image: "",
              position: "",
              repeat: "",
              size: "",
              opacity: 1
            },
            backgroundMask: {
              composite: "destination-out",
              cover: {
                color: {
                  value: "#fff"
                },
                opacity: 1
              },
              enable: false
            },
            clear: true,
            defaultThemes: {},
            delay: 0,
            fullScreen: {
              enable: false,
              zIndex: 1
            },
            detectRetina: true,
            duration: 0,
            fpsLimit: 120,
            interactivity: {
              detectsOn: "window",
              events: {
                onClick: {
                  enable: false,
                  mode: []
                },
                onDiv: {
                  selectors: [],
                  enable: false,
                  mode: [],
                  type: "circle"
                },
                onHover: {
                  enable: true,
                  mode: "light",
                  parallax: {
                    enable: false,
                    force: 2,
                    smooth: 10
                  }
                },
                resize: {
                  delay: 0.5,
                  enable: true
                }
              },
              modes: {
                trail: {
                  delay: 1,
                  pauseOnStop: false,
                  quantity: 1
                },
                attract: {
                  distance: 200,
                  duration: 0.4,
                  easing: "ease-out-quad",
                  factor: 1,
                  maxSpeed: 50,
                  speed: 1
                },
                bounce: {
                  distance: 200
                },
                bubble: {
                  distance: 200,
                  duration: 0.4,
                  mix: false,
                  divs: {
                    distance: 200,
                    duration: 0.4,
                    mix: false,
                    selectors: []
                  }
                },
                connect: {
                  distance: 80,
                  links: {
                    opacity: 0.5
                  },
                  radius: 60
                },
                grab: {
                  distance: 100,
                  links: {
                    blink: false,
                    consent: false,
                    opacity: 1
                  }
                },
                push: {
                  default: true,
                  groups: [],
                  quantity: 4
                },
                remove: {
                  quantity: 2
                },
                repulse: {
                  distance: 200,
                  duration: 0.4,
                  factor: 100,
                  speed: 1,
                  maxSpeed: 50,
                  easing: "ease-out-quad",
                  divs: {
                    distance: 200,
                    duration: 0.4,
                    factor: 100,
                    speed: 1,
                    maxSpeed: 50,
                    easing: "ease-out-quad",
                    selectors: []
                  }
                },
                slow: {
                  factor: 3,
                  radius: 200
                },
                light: {
                  area: {
                    gradient: {
                      start: {
                        value: "3b5e98"
                      },
                      stop: {
                        value: "#17163e"
                      }
                    },
                    radius: 1000
                  },
                  shadow: {
                    color: {
                      value: "#17163e"
                    },
                    length: 2000
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            manualParticles: [],
            particles: {
              bounce: {
                horizontal: {
                  value: 1
                },
                vertical: {
                  value: 1
                }
              },
              collisions: {
                absorb: {
                  speed: 2
                },
                bounce: {
                  horizontal: {
                    value: 1
                  },
                  vertical: {
                    value: 1
                  }
                },
                enable: false,
                maxSpeed: 50,
                mode: "bounce",
                overlap: {
                  enable: true,
                  retries: 0
                }
              },
              color: {
                value: "#ff0000",
                animation: {
                  h: {
                    count: 0,
                    enable: true,
                    speed: 20,
                    decay: 0,
                    delay: 0,
                    sync: true,
                    offset: 0
                  },
                  s: {
                    count: 0,
                    enable: false,
                    speed: 1,
                    decay: 0,
                    delay: 0,
                    sync: true,
                    offset: 0
                  },
                  l: {
                    count: 0,
                    enable: false,
                    speed: 1,
                    decay: 0,
                    delay: 0,
                    sync: true,
                    offset: 0
                  }
                }
              },
              effect: {
                close: true,
                fill: true,
                options: {},
                type: []
              },
              groups: {},
              move: {
                angle: {
                  offset: 0,
                  value: 90
                },
                attract: {
                  distance: 200,
                  enable: false,
                  rotate: {
                    x: 3000,
                    y: 3000
                  }
                },
                center: {
                  x: 50,
                  y: 50,
                  mode: "percent",
                  radius: 0
                },
                decay: 0,
                distance: {},
                direction: "none",
                drift: 0,
                enable: true,
                gravity: {
                  acceleration: 9.81,
                  enable: false,
                  inverse: false,
                  maxSpeed: 50
                },
                path: {
                  clamp: true,
                  delay: {
                    value: 0
                  },
                  enable: false,
                  options: {}
                },
                outModes: {
                  default: "out",
                  bottom: "out",
                  left: "out",
                  right: "out",
                  top: "out"
                },
                random: false,
                size: false,
                speed: 6,
                spin: {
                  acceleration: 0,
                  enable: false
                },
                straight: false,
                trail: {
                  enable: false,
                  length: 10,
                  fill: {}
                },
                vibrate: false,
                warp: false
              },
              number: {
                density: {
                  enable: true,
                  width: 1920,
                  height: 1080
                },
                limit: {
                  mode: "delete",
                  value: 0
                },
                value: 30
              },
              opacity: {
                value: 1,
                animation: {
                  count: 0,
                  enable: false,
                  speed: 2,
                  decay: 0,
                  delay: 0,
                  sync: false,
                  mode: "auto",
                  startValue: "random",
                  destroy: "none"
                }
              },
              reduceDuplicates: false,
              shadow: {
                blur: 0,
                color: {
                  value: "#000"
                },
                enable: false,
                offset: {
                  x: 0,
                  y: 0
                }
              },
              shape: {
                close: true,
                fill: true,
                options: {},
                type: [
                  "circle",
                  "square"
                ]
              },
              size: {
                value: {
                  min: 15,
                  max: 30
                },
                animation: {
                  count: 0,
                  enable: false,
                  speed: 5,
                  decay: 0,
                  delay: 0,
                  sync: false,
                  mode: "auto",
                  startValue: "random",
                  destroy: "none"
                }
              },
              stroke: {
                width: 0
              },
              zIndex: {
                value: 0,
                opacityRate: 1,
                sizeRate: 1,
                velocityRate: 1
              },
              destroy: {
                bounds: {},
                mode: "none",
                split: {
                  count: 1,
                  factor: {
                    value: 3
                  },
                  rate: {
                    value: {
                      min: 4,
                      max: 9
                    }
                  },
                  sizeOffset: true,
                  particles: {}
                }
              },
              roll: {
                darken: {
                  enable: false,
                  value: 0
                },
                enable: false,
                enlighten: {
                  enable: false,
                  value: 0
                },
                mode: "vertical",
                speed: 25
              },
              tilt: {
                value: 0,
                animation: {
                  enable: false,
                  speed: 0,
                  decay: 0,
                  sync: false
                },
                direction: "clockwise",
                enable: false
              },
              twinkle: {
                lines: {
                  enable: false,
                  frequency: 0.05,
                  opacity: 1
                },
                particles: {
                  enable: false,
                  frequency: 0.05,
                  opacity: 1
                }
              },
              wobble: {
                distance: 5,
                enable: false,
                speed: {
                  angle: 50,
                  move: 10
                }
              },
              life: {
                count: 0,
                delay: {
                  value: 0,
                  sync: false
                },
                duration: {
                  value: 0,
                  sync: false
                }
              },
              rotate: {
                value: 0,
                animation: {
                  enable: true,
                  speed: 5,
                  decay: 0,
                  sync: false
                },
                direction: "clockwise",
                path: false
              },
              orbit: {
                animation: {
                  count: 0,
                  enable: false,
                  speed: 1,
                  decay: 0,
                  delay: 0,
                  sync: false
                },
                enable: false,
                opacity: 1,
                rotation: {
                  value: 45
                },
                width: 1
              },
              links: {
                blink: false,
                color: {
                  value: "#fff"
                },
                consent: false,
                distance: 100,
                enable: false,
                frequency: 1,
                opacity: 1,
                shadow: {
                  blur: 5,
                  color: {
                    value: "#000"
                  },
                  enable: false
                },
                triangles: {
                  enable: false,
                  frequency: 1
                },
                width: 1,
                warp: false
              },
              repulse: {
                value: 0,
                enabled: false,
                distance: 1,
                duration: 1,
                factor: 1,
                speed: 1
              }
            },
            pauseOnBlur: true,
            pauseOnOutsideViewport: true,
            responsive: [],
            smooth: false,
            style: {},
            themes: [],
            zLayers: 100,
            emitters: [],
            motion: {
              disable: false,
              reduce: {
                factor: 4,
                value: true
              }
            }
          }

        }
        >

        </Particles>
    )
}

export default ParticlesBg
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Tried changing zIndex, tried isolating background by deleting everything from the page but just the particles to make sure that no other component was competing against the particle layer